# Bootstrap3 .visible-* .hidden-* display inline

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

Bootstrap has some nice `.visible-*` (eg. `.visible-lg`) class utility for selecting what to show or hide depending on the screen size.

When using those classes, it applies the styling `display: block !important;` when in the correct screen size.

But sometimes, I'd like to use it for some elements that are displayed `inline` or `inline-block`.

How could I cleanly override some bootstrap rules to have the choice? Or should it be a feature request in bootstrap?

---

EDIT

Seems like I'm not the only one wondering about this issue. Here's the [github issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/8869).

Thanks for the latest answer!

Comment: This was already proposed and rejected: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/8869

Comment: Not sure they totally rejected it. They mention v3.1 at the end. Having `.visible-inline-lg` makes much sense to me.

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger, Looks like they fixed this in v.3.2.0 with the addition of display specific responsive visibility classes.  See my answer with the full update.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

### Update for Bootstrap v3.2.0

This is now natively solved in Bootstrap v3.2.0 with [this commit](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/bdd7651e323a93a4e3d207463451dd374b0a70fa)

According to the [new responsive classes documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities):

> As of v3.2.0, the .visible-*-* classes for each breakpoint come in three variations, one for each CSS display property value listed below:

```
Group of classes          | CSS display
 .visible-*-block         |  display: block;
 .visible-*-inline        |  display: inline;
 .visible-*-inline-block  |  display: inline-block;
```

For example, you could use:

```html
<p>Device is: <span class="visible-lg-inline">Large</span></p>
```

---

### Other Instances

Asked about on Stackoverflow:

- [Bootstrap 3 class visible-lg moves span to a new line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23302759/1366033)

Reported in Bootstrap Issues:

- [#4929 - Responsive utility classes may cause unexpected wrapping](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/4929)
- [#7808 - Using display inherit in responsive utilities causes elements to be wrongly displayed](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/7808)
- [#8500 - responsive class usage with inline element](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/8500)
- [#8869 - responsive .hidden-* classes change from display block to inline-block](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/8869)
- [#10263 - visible-xs makes display=block even for inline elements](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10263)

Comment: Thanks, for the update.  Any idea why they didn't create `.hidden-*-*`?

Comment: @Kekito, `hidden-*` wasn't broken because it would [only hide elements based on screenwidth](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/bdd7651e323a93a4e3d207463451dd374b0a70fa/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L5815), which didn't require positing a display type

Comment: Great that .visible-*-block is available. But why is the counterpart .hidden-*-block not available?

Answer (score 15):

This has been sort of fixed in v3.1.

`.visible-lg` or `.visible-md` will force `display: block !important;` but using `.hidden-xs` or `.hidden-sm` will display inline.

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger It solves the display inline problem by using `hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-lg` instead of `visiblem-md`.

Comment: Doesn't "hidden" do the exact opposite of "visible", though?

Comment: hidden will hide from the size you choose , visible will show from the screen size you need

Answer (score 13):

The following library extends the visible helper classes with inline & inline-block variations:

https://github.com/moappi/bootstrap.inline-responsive

Implements the following:

- `visible-inline-*`
- `hidden-inline-*`

and

- `visible-inline-block-*`
- `hidden-inline-block-*`

Answer (score 1):

Updating to bootstrap 3.1 or above indeed solves the problem as from this point on the `hidden-` classes only hide the tag and don't set `display: block` anymore. This way you can use `<div>` for block context and `<span>` for inline-block context (the normal behavior of these tags)