# Bootstrap 3 class visible-lg moves span to a new line

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I make class `visible-lg` not to move the span to a new line?

The following HTML renders as one line:

```
<p>Device is:<span>Unknown</span></p>
```

*However*, the following HTML renders `Large` on the line below `Device is`:

```
<p>Device is:<span class="visible-lg">Large</span></p>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bootstrap3 .visible-\* .hidden-\* display inline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098376/bootstrap3-visible-hidden-display-inline)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Update for Bootstrap v3.2.0

This is now natively solved in Bootstrap v3.2.0 with [this commit](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/bdd7651e323a93a4e3d207463451dd374b0a70fa)

According to the [responsive classes documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities):

> As of v3.2.0, the .visible-*-* classes for each breakpoint come in three variations, one for each CSS display property value listed below:

```
Group of classes          | CSS display
 .visible-*-block         |  display: block;
 .visible-*-inline        |  display: inline;
 .visible-*-inline-block  |  display: inline-block;
```

So in your case, you'd want to use:

```html
<p>Device is:<span class="visible-lg-inline">Large</span></p>
```

---

### Original for Bootstrap v3.0

In Bootstrap 3.0, all visible and hidden responsive classes use `display:block !important;`
You'll have to override that if you want to display elements inline:

```css
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  span.visible-lg {
    display: inline !important
  }
}
```

### [Working Demo in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/pH8xv/)

For a more robust approach, here is a [library that adds extension classes for each display type](https://github.com/moappi/bootstrap.inline-responsive)

---

### Other Instances

Asked about on Stackoverflow:

- [Bootstrap3 .visible-* .hidden-* display inline](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19098376/1366033)

Reported in Bootstrap Issues:

- [#4929 - Responsive utility classes may cause unexpected wrapping](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/4929)
- [#7808 - Using display inherit in responsive utilities causes elements to be wrongly displayed](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/7808)
- [#8500 - responsive class usage with inline element](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/8500)
- [#8869 - responsive .hidden-* classes change from display block to inline-block](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/8869)
- [#10263 - visible-xs makes display=block even for inline elements](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10263)

Comment: Kyle, sorry I didn't see your reply earlier. I found - after posting my answer - that inline with !important does not work at all. What happens is when I have "display: inline !important" the "visible-lg" is completely ignored.  I will try now using the CSS style as you suggest to see if it works better.
Thank you very much!

Comment: @Hidalgo, no problem!  Glad you're figuring out stuff on your own too!  A good rule of thumb is to stick around for a while after asking a question, as it's a prime window for follow up questions.  But it's not a big deal here.  Also remember to accept any answers to questions that you ask that best solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this issue is to set inline style for the span of class="visible_lg" as follows:

```
style="display: inline !important"
```

The "!important" is the key since Bootstrap 3 sets this style to "block !important"