# Change body of table according to the screen

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table, responsive-design

I am using bootstrap 3, I have a table that must change the body according to the size of the screen. Look about the css rules (@media), it's an option but I wanted it to work like the responsive table so I do not have to indicate what the size is but it only identifies if the columns do not fit the current size of the screen

```
<table>
  <thead>
      <tr class="fullScreen">
        ...
      </tr> 
      <tr class="smartScreen">
        ...
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr class="fullScreen">
         ...
      </tr> 
      <tr class="smartScreen">
         ...
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: If, you can not show all the columns that are inside "fullscreen" then show "smartscreen"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using bootstrap 3.3.7 then this code will help you,
you just put class="table table-responsive" in your table tag. The table will be responsive.

```
<style>
    .table-responsive 
    { border: 0px !important; }
</style>



<body>
  <table class="table table-responsive">
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <td> col 1 </td>
       <td> col 2 </td>
     </tr> 
     <tr class="smartScreen">
       <td> col 1 </td>
       <td> col 2 </td>
    </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
    <tr class="fullScreen">
      <td> col 1 </td>
      <td> col 2 </td>
    </tr> 
    <tr class="smartScreen">
      <td> col 1 </td>
      <td> col 2 </td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Display property should work.

Display property https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display

**How it works**

Change the value of the display property with our responsive display utility classes. We purposely support only a subset of all possible values for display. Classes can be combined for various effects as you need.

Hiding elements

```
Hidden on all   .d-none
Hidden only on xs   .d-none .d-sm-block
Hidden only on sm   .d-sm-none .d-md-block
Hidden only on md   .d-md-none .d-lg-block
Hidden only on lg   .d-lg-none .d-xl-block
Hidden only on xl   .d-xl-none
Visible on all  .d-block
Visible only on xs  .d-block .d-sm-none
Visible only on sm  .d-none .d-sm-block .d-md-none
Visible only on md  .d-none .d-md-block .d-lg-none
Visible only on lg  .d-none .d-lg-block .d-xl-none
Visible only on xl  .d-none .d-xl-block
```

Comment: i don't talk about of grid system, i want that only one is shown

Comment: If this works, could you click the mark to show that this is the correct answer?

Comment: The answer refers to bootstrap 4 and the question indicates that bootstrap 3 is used

Comment: Oops, sorry. Bootstrap 3 apparently has for example .visible-lg. This question might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098376/bootstrap3-visible-hidden-display-inline